# C language about input ouput with prinf function i exactly type yes but why can't i see output?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    char name[40];      
    scanf("%s",name);

   if(name == "yes")    
   {
       printf("%s",name);
   }

   return 0
}
```

Comment: search for string comparison issues,

Comment: You are comparing pointers, not strings.

Comment: thank you so much can i ask why if(name=="yes") is not avalible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `strcmp` for string comparison.

Replace

```
if(name == "yes")
```

With

```
if(strcmp(name,"yes") == 0)
```

---

`strcmp` returns

1. > 0 if both strings are identical (equal)
2. > Negative value    if the ASCII value of first unmatched character is less than second.
3. > Positive value if the
   >   ASCII value of first unmatched character is greater than second.

Comment: thank you so much can i ask why if(name=="yes") is not avalible?

Comment: @richbak: It has to do with how C treats array expressions - under most circumstances, an expression of array type "decays" to a pointer, so what you wind up comparing are the *addresses* of the strings, not their contents.  There is a reason for this behavior, but it's more than will fit into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

`==` isn't defined for string (or any other array) comparisons - you need to use the standard library function `strcmp` to compare strings:

```
if ( strcmp( name, "yes" ) == 0 )
```

or

```
if ( !strcmp( name, "yes") )
```

`strcmp` is a little non-intuitive in that it returns 0 if the string contents are equal, so the sense of the test will feel wrong.  It will return a negative value if the first string is lexicographically less than the second, and a positive value if the first string is lexicographically greater than the second.

You'll need to `#include <string.h>` in order to use `strcmp`.

For comparing arrays that aren't strings, use `memcmp`.